# Logging the value of a future before returning it in Scala

Tags: scala

```
def returnFuture[A](x: A): Future[A] = {
      val xFuture = Future { x } // suppose an API call that returns a future
       xFuture.flatMap(x => {
            println(x) // logging the value of x
            xFuture
        })
    }
```

This is the way I'm currently doing it. To provide more context:

This function is being called inside an API when a request is made and I'd like the log message to be printed just before the value computed in the request is returned. Which is why, the following is not a good solution for me:

```
def returnFuture[A](x: A): Future[A] = {
      val xFuture = Future { x } // suppose an API call that returns a future
       xFuture.map(x => {
            println(x) // logging the value of x
        })
      xFuture
    }
```

Comment: ` = { println(x); Future(x) }` or am I missing something here?

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov, not sure what you mean here.

Comment: "while the request is being handled" in your case is the same as "before the request has been handled" because you have a single indivisible unit of work and you don't control when the Future will execute. If you want to print after use `map`, `flatMap`, or `onComplete`/`onSuccess`. You question is a bit confusing because you ask for "while the request is being handled", but show the code for "after it's been handled, just before value is returned".

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov, agreed. I should have specified, after the value is computed after handling but before the value is returned. Edited for clarity

Answer (score 5):

Logging is a side-effect, meaning that you don't want the operation to fail if the logging fails for any reason (e.g. a call to `toString` throwing NPE).

[`Future#andThen`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen%5BU%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5Bscala.util.Try%5BT%5D,U%5D)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D) is perfect for this use case. From the docs:

> Applies the side-effecting function to the result of this future, and returns a new future with the result of this future.
>
> This method allows one to enforce that the callbacks are executed in a specified order.
>
> Note that if one of the chained `andThen` callbacks throws an exception, that exception is not propagated to the subsequent `andThen` callbacks. Instead, the subsequent `andThen` callbacks are given the original value of this future.

Your example becomes:

```
def returnFuture[A](x: A): Future[A] = {
  Future { x } // suppose an API call that returns a future
    .andThen { case Success(v) => println(v) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onComplete` callback:

```
def returnFuture[A](x: A): Future[A] = {
  val f = Future { x }
  f.onComplete(println)
  f
}
```

A map will work too:

```
def returnFuture[A](x: A): Future[A] = {
  Future { x }.map { v =>
    println(v)
    v
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the whole point of using `Futures` is that you are trying to avoid blocking and that you don't control exactly when the `Future` will be executed. So, if you want more detailed logs while keeping the asynchronous nature of a `Future`, do something like this:

```
def doSomething(param: String): String = {
  // log something here
  val result = param.toUpperCase
  // log something else here
  result
}

def asFuture(param: String) = Future {
  doSomething(param)
}
```

In other words, if this is an option, add logs to the `x` operation instead.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I missed the most obvious Future{x}.map {v => ...} Thanks!